# how to display .xls or word file in ngx-doc-viewer angular 8?

Tags: angular8, ngx-doc-viewer

I want to display .xls or word in file my previewer.

I am using ngx-doc-viewer.

can anyone tell me how can i do this?

html code for previewer:

```
           <ngx-doc-viewer [viewerUrl]="'https://docs.google.com/gview?url=%URL%&embedded=true'" 
           [url]="path"viewer="url">
           </ngx-doc-viewer>
    
   
    -in [url] i had given path of my server folder
```